# Use Dvorak layout on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I use computers where I don't have access to the control panel to add/change keyboard layouts, but would like to use the Dvorak layout on these computers.

Is there some software that will remap the keystrokes to the appropriate dvorak ones?

Comment: So you have rights to install software but not get to the keymapping in the control panel? Odd security.

Comment: Yes, most software will install just fine, it will be reset at next boot, though (Clean Slate). So I guess some program that would just change that registry setting for keyboard layout would also work. Interesting thought.

Answer (score 0):

I found this AutoHotKey script, which I just compiled into a handy little 202 KB .exe file - http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic27474.html Works like a charm, and completely portable!